# Realm does not want to update values of RLMObject properties

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am using Realm in my new iOS project. I am inserting new `RLMObject` like this:

```
let realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()
var route = Route()
route.status = "opened"

realm.beginWriteTransaction()
realm.addObject(route)
realm.commitWriteTransaction()
```

And I want to update `route` status like this (in separate function):

```
let realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()
let openedRoutes = Route.objectsWhere("status == 'opened'")
var openedRoute = openedRoutes.objectAtIndex(0) as Route

realm.beginWriteTransaction()
openedRoute.status = "closed"
realm.commitWriteTransaction()
```

But it does not update anything.

What I am doing wrong? Thank you for time and help.

**Additional info**

When I do for example `po self`, there are errors in log:

```
error: Error in auto-import:
failed to get module '*' from AST context:
/Users/peterdruska/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Cesty-hijwnftlnwubfmgymqpszfmjojrr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Pods/Realm.framework/Headers/Pods-Realm-umbrella.h:3:9: note: in file included from /Users/peterdruska/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Cesty-hijwnftlnwubfmgymqpszfmjojrr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Pods/Realm.framework/Headers/Pods-Realm-umbrella.h:3:
#import "RLMArray.h"

…
```

I have Realm installed using cocoa pods.

Answer (score 0):

Do you access the object from the same Realm on the same thread, directly after updating it, to ensure that your changes were applied? Are there perhaps any simultaneous write transactions happening, which would block the changes from taking effect? If not, where and when are you missing the propagation of your modifications?

If it's another Realm, then you can only expect updated properties as soon as the write transaction was comitted and the Realm was notified, which you can ensure by using the [Notification API](http://realm.io/docs/cocoa/0.91.1/#notifications), e.g:

```
let token = realm.addNotificationBlock { note, realm in
    assert(self.lastOpenedRoute.status == "closed")
}
```

#### Regarding your additional info

That seems to be [a known issue with CocoaPods & LLDB](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3092), which we haven't addressed yet.

Comment: Thank you, marius. Everything is in the same thread. But as you mentioned, when I've installed Realm not using CocoaPods, everything works fine.